# Reading string from a file by using getchar

Tags: c, string, while-loop, getchar

Trying to create a C program that can execute bash commands, and I'm trying to do this by reading commands from a text file. The problem I'm having is getchar is perfect for reading single characters like 1, 2, 3 etc but I'm struggling to have a string that's more than one character.

My code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


// the only variables that are used
char choice;
char str[50], dirName;
int i;
int finished = 1;

while(finished) {

printChoice(); // only prints to terminal [1] to cd [2] to exit prog

choice = getchar();
dirName = getchar();
 
switch(choice){
    case ('1'):
        while(dirName !='\n') { // im sure i've placed this while loop in the wrong place but I dont know any better
            str[i] = dirName;
            i++;
            dirName = getchar(); 
        }

        printf("Enter directory you'd like to move into: ");
        changeDir(str); // function to cd
        break; 

    case ('2'): // exit program
        printf("Closing Program...\n");
        finished=0;
        break;

    default: // incorrect user choice
        printf("Invalid choice\n\n");
        break;
    }
}
    
return 0;}
```

The text file input I'm trying to read (if I just run the program with 1 2, the program works as intended):

```
1 Documents 2
```

Desired output:

```
cd Documents // once finished
exit program
```

Comment: Use `fgets` to read a line and parse the commands